# Can a python class be declared to have the same __init__() signature as another class (including defaults)?

Tags: python, wrapper, factory, introspection, inspect

Consider the following wrapper:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(arg1='default1', arg2='default2'):
        # initialize stuff

    def do_stuff(self):

    
class SomeClassWrapper:
    def __init__(arg1='default1', arg2='default2'):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
    
    def doit(self):
        instance = SomeClass(arg1, arg2)
        instance.do_stuff()
```

`SomeClassWrapper` is there to delay instantiation of `SomeClass` objects and to abstract away the creation of a new instance every time `do_stuff()` needs to be performed.

`SomeClassWrapper` is initialized with the "template" required to later initialize `SomeClass` objects whose real life initialization list is much longer than in the example and subject to change as the project develops.

The goal is to reduce errors and maintenance burden by not having to manually retype the same argument list (including defaults) in `SomeClassWrapper.__init__()` that we already have in `SomeClass.__init__()`.

Is there a way, perhaps using the `inspect` module, to do something along the lines of the below?

```
class SomeClassWrapper:
    # syntax to say:
    #  __init__() should be the same as SomeClass.__init__()  
    #  the arguments should be stored in say self.kwargs
    
    def doit(self)
        instance = SomeClass(self.kwargs)
        instance.do_stuff()
```

Comment: You can use `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` in the subclass and pass them to `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than duplicate the argument passing, have the wrapper accept a zero-argument callable that creates the object.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(arg1='default1', arg2='default2'):
        # initialize stuff

    def do_stuff(self):
        ...

    
class SomeClassWrapper:
    def __init__(self, maker):
        self.maker = maker

    def doit(self):
        instance = self.maker()
        instance.do_stuff()
```

The caller still provides all the details, but in a slightly different fashion

```
# Old version
# w = SomeClassWrapper('foo', 'bar)

# One option
w = SomeClassWrapper(lambda: SomeClass('foo', 'bar'))

# Another option
from functools import partial
w = SomeClassWrapper(partial(SomeClass, 'foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. I also like erip's *args and **kwargs in the comment he posted. One thing here is that the caller needs to know what we are wrapping which we may want to keep hidden, but I suppose that the *args and **kwargs solution doesn't hide very much as the caller still needs to look at the wrapped class to figure out the signature

Answer (score 1):

You can use your wrapper as a template you inherit from, and create new wrappers per class you need a wrapper for.

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, arg1='default1', arg2='default2'):
        # Initialize stuff

    def do_stuff(self):
        # Do stuff


class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self, hello='a'):
        # Initialize stuff

    def do_stuff(self):
        # Do stuff

    

class BaseClassWrapper:
    instance_class = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args   = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
    
    def doit(self):
        instance = self.instance_class(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        instance.do_stuff()


class SomeClassWrapper(BaseClassWrapper):
    instance_class = SomeClass

class AnotherClassWrapper(BaseClassWrapper):
    instance_class = AnotherClass


wrapper1 = SomeClassWrapper('arg1', arg2='arg2')
wrapper1.doit()

wrapper2 = AnotherClassWrapper('goodbye')
wrapper2.doit()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Nice solution. I like how it makes it explicit to the caller what is being wrapped. I suppose one could type hints the maker in chepner's solution to achieve a similar thing. I'll mark his as the answer for its slight edge on brevity and a somewhat subjective preference.